# how to display text on label in single line

Tags: highcharts

I want to dispaly label text in one line on horizontal bar in highcharts. below is the code.I want to dispaly label text in one line on horizontal bar in highcharts. below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="container" style="min-width: 100%; max-width:100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        marginLeft:120,
        marginBottom: 100,
        type:'bar'
    },
    credits: {enabled: false},
    legend: { 
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        margin: 50
    },
    title: {text: null},
    tooltip: {},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: '#006666',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        color: '#00FF00',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: '#FF8C00',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Computer Devices & Accessories', 'Computer Peripherals Hire & Repair Services', 'Computer Laptop Hardware & Peripherals', 'Computer Stationery, Hard disk, Ram, Pen Drives & Other Products', 'Internet Accessories'],
        labels: {
            align:'left',
            x:5,
            style: {
                fontSize: '1em',
                color:'#fff'
            }
        }

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
    }       
});



    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a better example of what I want to accomplish

I want to dispaly label text in one line on horizontal bar in highcharts. below is the code.I want to dispaly label text in one line on horizontal bar in highcharts. below is the code

Comment: *"Given the below image"* Which image ?

Comment: i edited question @Core972

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an `width` for your labels

```
...
style: {
            fontSize: '1em',
            color:'#fff',
            width:'500px'
        }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/a0Lcsyeh/)

*As you can see the 4th bar is too short so you will have to set the width for a second line appear*

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below property in label

```
label{
display:block
}
```

Comment: block is not working . can you just create a fiddle for it @PPL